# Element sorting by attribute

Tags: xslt, sorting

I am new to xsl(t).

After reading quite some topics about this the confusion ist getting bigger than smaller. I have to transform a subsection of an xml-file by an attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<Rechnung AuftragsReferenz="" MarketingCode="KAN00" Auftragsart="Normal" Auftragsherkunft="Schriftlich" AnzahlPakete="1" ZuZahlenderBetrag="94.30" SummeNebenerloeseNetto="6.07" SummeNebenerloeseBrutto="6.50" EnthalteneMWST="7.86" BetragNetto="86.44" BetragBrutto="94.30" Rechnungsdatum="25.05.2012" Rechnungsnummer="123456789" Zahlungskanal="Rechnung">
    <RechnungArtikelpositionen>
        <RechnungArtikelposition EinzelPreisNetto="0.00" EinzelPreisBrutto="0.00" GesamtPreisNetto="0.00" GesamtPreisBrutto="0.00" Menge="1.00">
            <Rechnungnebenerloese/>
            <RechnungMehrwertsteuer Prozentsatz="19.00" Steuerbetrag="2.87" Nettobetrag="15.08"/>
            <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Geschenk" ArtikeltypId="8" Zusatztextkennzeichen="1" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="82000" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Dankeschön" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
            <Ersatzartikel Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="12345" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Geschenk: EinGeschenk" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
        </RechnungArtikelposition>
        <RechnungArtikelposition EinzelPreisNetto="15.08" EinzelPreisBrutto="17.95" GesamtPreisNetto="15.08" GesamtPreisBrutto="17.95" Menge="1.00">
            <Rechnungnebenerloese/>
            <RechnungMehrwertsteuer Prozentsatz="19.00" Steuerbetrag="2.87" Nettobetrag="15.08"/>
            <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Keine Absage" AbsagekennzeichenId="1" Artikeltyp="Verkauf" ArtikeltypId="0" Zusatztextkennzeichen="1" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="54321" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Massageöl Latschenkiefer" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
            <Ersatzartikel/>
        </RechnungArtikelposition>
        <RechnungArtikelposition EinzelPreisNetto="27.99" EinzelPreisBrutto="29.95" GesamtPreisNetto="27.99" GesamtPreisBrutto="29.95" Menge="1.00">
            <Rechnungnebenerloese/>
            <RechnungMehrwertsteuer Prozentsatz="7.00" Steuerbetrag="4.99" Nettobetrag="71.36"/>
            <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Keine Absage" AbsagekennzeichenId="1" Artikeltyp="Verkauf" ArtikeltypId="0" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="44444" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Knoblauchkapseln 60 Stück   +" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
            <Ersatzartikel/>
        </RechnungArtikelposition>
        <RechnungArtikelposition EinzelPreisNetto="18.64" EinzelPreisBrutto="19.95" GesamtPreisNetto="37.28" GesamtPreisBrutto="39.90" Menge="2.00">
            <Rechnungnebenerloese/>
            <RechnungMehrwertsteuer Prozentsatz="7.00" Steuerbetrag="4.99" Nettobetrag="71.36"/>
            <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Keine Absage" AbsagekennzeichenId="1" Artikeltyp="Verkauf" ArtikeltypId="0" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="55555" Bestellmenge="2.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Echte Sauerampfer Kapseln 60 St.+" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
            <Ersatzartikel/>
        </RechnungArtikelposition>
    </RechnungArtikelpositionen>
<other things />
</Rechnung>
```

The "Artikelposition"s should be sorted by "EinzelPreisBrutto"

I tried several variations, the latest being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Rechnung">
           <xsl:copy-of select="RechnungArtikelpositionen" />
             <xsl:apply-templates select="RechnungArtikelposition">
                <xsl:sort select="@EinzelPreisBrutto" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
             </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but no sorting occurs. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSLT is not actually currently valid the **xsl:copy-of** function should not contain any elements within it (It is used just to copy an element 'as-is'

Also, you need to make sure when you apply the templates for **RechnungArtikelposition** you are positioned on the correct parent element of **RechnungArtikelpositionen**. In your code sample, the current posistion would be the document element of the XML.

Instead of using xsl:copy-of, try working with the identity template with an extra template to match **RechnungArtikelpositionen** and then sort the children.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="RechnungArtikelpositionen">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="RechnungArtikelposition">
            <xsl:sort select="@EinzelPreisBrutto" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<Rechnung AuftragsReferenz="" MarketingCode="KAN00" Auftragsart="Normal" Auftragsherkunft="Schriftlich" AnzahlPakete="1" ZuZahlenderBetrag="94.30" SummeNebenerloeseNetto="6.07" SummeNebenerloeseBrutto="6.50" EnthalteneMWST="7.86" BetragNetto="86.44" BetragBrutto="94.30" Rechnungsdatum="25.05.2012" Rechnungsnummer="123456789" Zahlungskanal="Rechnung">
   <RechnungArtikelpositionen>
      <RechnungArtikelposition EinzelPreisNetto="27.99" EinzelPreisBrutto="29.95" GesamtPreisNetto="27.99" GesamtPreisBrutto="29.95" Menge="1.00">
         <Rechnungnebenerloese/>
         <RechnungMehrwertsteuer Prozentsatz="7.00" Steuerbetrag="4.99" Nettobetrag="71.36"/>
         <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Keine Absage" AbsagekennzeichenId="1" Artikeltyp="Verkauf" ArtikeltypId="0" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="44444" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Knoblauchkapseln 60 Stück   +" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
         <Ersatzartikel/>
      </RechnungArtikelposition>
      <RechnungArtikelposition EinzelPreisNetto="18.64" EinzelPreisBrutto="19.95" GesamtPreisNetto="37.28" GesamtPreisBrutto="39.90" Menge="2.00">
         <Rechnungnebenerloese/>
         <RechnungMehrwertsteuer Prozentsatz="7.00" Steuerbetrag="4.99" Nettobetrag="71.36"/>
         <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Keine Absage" AbsagekennzeichenId="1" Artikeltyp="Verkauf" ArtikeltypId="0" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="55555" Bestellmenge="2.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Echte Sauerampfer Kapseln 60 St.+" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
         <Ersatzartikel/>
      </RechnungArtikelposition>
      <RechnungArtikelposition EinzelPreisNetto="15.08" EinzelPreisBrutto="17.95" GesamtPreisNetto="15.08" GesamtPreisBrutto="17.95" Menge="1.00">
         <Rechnungnebenerloese/>
         <RechnungMehrwertsteuer Prozentsatz="19.00" Steuerbetrag="2.87" Nettobetrag="15.08"/>
         <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Keine Absage" AbsagekennzeichenId="1" Artikeltyp="Verkauf" ArtikeltypId="0" Zusatztextkennzeichen="1" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="54321" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Massageöl Latschenkiefer" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
         <Ersatzartikel/>
      </RechnungArtikelposition>
      <RechnungArtikelposition EinzelPreisNetto="0.00" EinzelPreisBrutto="0.00" GesamtPreisNetto="0.00" GesamtPreisBrutto="0.00" Menge="1.00">
         <Rechnungnebenerloese/>
         <RechnungMehrwertsteuer Prozentsatz="19.00" Steuerbetrag="2.87" Nettobetrag="15.08"/>
         <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Geschenk" ArtikeltypId="8" Zusatztextkennzeichen="1" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="82000" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Dankeschön" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
         <Ersatzartikel Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="12345" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Geschenk: EinGeschenk" Katalogkennzeichen="K4"/>
      </RechnungArtikelposition>
   </RechnungArtikelpositionen>
   <otherthings/>
</Rechnung>
```